# BizTalk: Should I care this: "Failed to recover from previous error. Database: BizTalkMsgBoxDb"

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

BizTalk Server complains from time to time:

```
Reading error. Failed to recover from previous error. SQLServer: XXX, Database: BizTalkMsgBoxDb.
```

Should I care this, or simply ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a temporary loss of connectivity to the MessageBox. Not good, but also not critical as long as connectivity is restored quickly enough. The specific error message relates to BAM, which you can switch off if not being used. However, the problem will affect BizTalk as a whole.

You would have to find out what's causing the loss of connectivity and address that. Might not be easy, mind you, I have seen this happening on DEV boxes with both BizTalk and SQL Server on the same box...

[BizTalk Server 2006: BAM FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972199%28BTS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I think I disabled BAM tools and irritating message disappeared. (**Start > All Programs > Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010 > BizTalk Server Configuration** and then under **BAM Tools** unchecked **Remove the Business Activity Monitoring tools for this BizTalk Group**)

Comment: No, continues to appear :/ How to disable it?

Comment: The BAM Event Bus Service runs within the context of a BizTalk tracking host instance. To disable it, you need to use hosts that have tracking disabled - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559857.aspx for more details

Comment: But be careful about disabling Tracking on all hosts. If you use BizTalk Tracking and there are no hosts with Tracking Enabled, running, you will end up just backing up all the tracked messages in the MsgBoxDB. I've been there  :-)

Answer (score 1):

As per Fabio, the message you received is likely to be specific to BAM.

The types of error that you get in your eventlog if BizTalk hosts and ENTSSO does lose connectivity with SQL are listed [here](http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar-SA/biztalkgeneral/thread/ecbd0197-1bb7-4215-a33a-71334945020c)

These errors are more serious and can result in the loss of messages (Hosts and Receive Locations are usually stopped).

These errors can occur intermittently and then a minute or two later you see

> Communication with MessageBox BizTalkMsgBoxDb on SQL Instance XXX has
>   been re-established

Common causes of BizTalk : SQL Connectivity issues are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa952081%28v=bts.20%29.aspx)

We've found the usual culprit of connectivity issues to be the [TCP/IP SynAttackProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560429%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) security feature on the SQL Server host - BizTalk can hog a lot of SQL Connections, especially during a 'ramp up' of connections required when a batch of messages comes in after a protacted idle period.